# Loading scripts after executing a specific function

Tags: javascript

There is such a code that sends data, depending on the visitor, I redirect it to another subdomain.

```
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();


var url = 'https://example/handler.php';
var params = 'key=' + 'XXX' + "&value=" + 'XXX';
http.open('POST', url, true);

http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

http.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
    document.location.href = http.responseText;
  }
 }
   http.send(params);
```

Initially there is a page in index.php, but if I need to redirect it to another domain?

It turns out that I am loading index.php, and then another page that returned from the subquery.

How can I block further execution of scripts, html, css, script and wait for the request to be executed from the server, and then either continue further or redirect?

I tried  New Promise,
did not help

the goal is to redirect the subdomain to another or continue to load the index.php page

Comment: You could inject the scripts and styles tags into the dom after your request had completed

Comment: To be honest this isn't making a lot of sense. When you redirect using `document.location.href` a whole new page loads and the script in current page is gone. Sounds more like a server side issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by making a ***synchronous*** ajax call. This will block the page from loading until the request is completed.

But you might want to keep in mind that this is a bad practice.

```
xhr.open("POST",url,false);
```

Comment: It was the right decision, I wonder if it stops working if you put it in a function.

Comment: @Daheim I don't think so, are you facing any issues?